# database structure for ranking system

Tags: php, database

I'm making a PHP battle system, and need to sort out the ranking.

How I want it to work is say there's 100 players, and you're rank 90. You can challenge players 5 ranks above, so say you challenge and beat the player in rank 85, then YOU become 85 and he becomes 86.

I'm not sure how to do this with a database though. How to set it out, or store rank. Obviously I can't save a field with your 'rank' since if you win it'd have to edit every single players rank below you in the database, wouldn't it?

Any ideas would be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend you **do** keep a rank field and relax the bottleneck in the queries:

In your example use something like

```
UPDATE players 
SET rank=IF(playerid=<id-of-challengin-player>,rank-5,rank+1) 
WHERE rank>=85 AND rank<=90
```

This will change ranks

```
old   new
85    86
86    87
87    88
88    89
89    90
90    85
```

which looks like what you want, but uses a single query, that can leverage an index and touches only 6 rows.

**Edit**

To facilitate maintenance (fix rank numbers, if there are holes etc.), run

```
CREATE VIEW players_by_rank AS 
SELECT * FROM players ORDER BY rank
```

once, then use

```
UPDATE (SELECT @newrank:=0) AS init, players_by_rank 
SET score=(@newrank:=@newrank+1)
```

to close gaps in the table. Mind that this touches all rows!

Comment: thanks, I didn't realize it would only update 6, i was mistakenly thinking it'd have to edit all ranks below you.

Comment: if a record gets deleted too, that'd mess things up :o

Comment: You typically fix this by not really deleting the record (at first), but setting a field, something like `SET active=0`. You then run `UPDATE players SET rank=IF(playerid=[id of deleted player],-1*rank,rank-1) WHERE rank>[rank of deleted player]`, which puts your deleted player at an invalid rank, where you can delete it without harm.

Comment: I was thinking of a query that sorts all fields if there's any gaps in the ranks. Or that.

Comment: This is also a possibility: Do `CREATE VIEW players_by_rank AS SELECT * FROM players ORDER BY rank` once, then use `UPDATE (SELECT @newrank:=0) AS init, players_by_rank SET score=(@newrank:=@newrank+1);` to close gaps in the table. Mind that this touches all rows!

Answer (score 1):

You could indeed have a rank column in the database and update along the lines of: `update yourtable set playerRank=playerRank+1 where playerRank>85` then update the winning player to be playerRank 85. That might be hitting a lot of records, but it wouldn't be a heavy cost to the database.

Answer (score 0):

Since the 'rank' you describe is not based on any other rules, such as points.. something that can be calculated, you must store this rank everywhere.

And yea, that does imply that you need to update a whole bunch of records every time; but since you mention you can only challenge up to 5 positions ahead of you, this also implies that you only ever have to update 6 records every time.. (no big deal)

```
90 -> 85
89 -> 90
88 -> 89
87 -> 88
86 -> 87
85 -> 86
```

Comment: Sorry, didn't want to copycat ... I was writing my answer while you submitted yours